# 3 PWM pins for RGB LED

Tags: gpio, python, led, pwm

I got an RGB LED, one mass and one for blue, red, green. So I got a list there are only two PWM compatible pins listed. Pin 32(GPIO 12) and pin 33(GPIO 13). But for my RBG LED I need three pins with PWM to dim the single color for mixing new colors. So is there another pin I can use for PWM or can't I dim the RGB LED, but in theory I can dim the RGB LED.
PS: I code in python
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You can control the common(ground) with PWM if you are trying to dim all three at the same time. Then use any gpio to turn on/off each color as you need it. But this will not work if you need to change the brightness of just one color

Comment: I need to dim all three individual is there a third PWM pin I van use

Comment: I would look for a multi channel pwm board that you can talk to with I2C. Something like this https://www.amazon.com/Channel-Driver-interface-PCA9685-arduino-Raspberry/dp/B01D9VNXEQ/ref=sr_1_2_sspa?ie=UTF8&qid=1544558451&sr=8-2-spons&keywords=pwm+module+I2C&psc=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) provides hardware timed PWM on any of GPIO 0-31.

C, Python, and from the command line (pigs).

No need to waste money on additional hardware.